# Sequentially add plots to list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a large number of ggplots, which I would like to add to a list, so that I can create a pdf from the entire list in one go.

```
myplots <- list()

#generate ggplot1
ggplot1 -> myplots[[1]]

#generate ggplot2
ggplot2 -> myplots[[2]]

#many more ggplots

pdf("myplots.pdf")
for (i in myplots) {
  print(i)
}
dev.off()
```

Is there a less repetitive way to code this? For instance, I'd like to add the plots at the end of the list, without having to specify the position numerically (`[[2]]` etc), as I might rearrange the plots in the future.

**Edit** I found this solution which eliminates the need to sequentially add the plots to the list.

```
myplots <- mget(ls(pattern = "plot"))


pdf("yopd.pdf")
for (i in myplots) {
  print(i)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Use forloop, same way you used with print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a useful pattern you can use `ls()` to list your plots. Getting them using `mget` will be sufficient then.

```
pdf('foo.pdf')
mget(ls(pattern='ggplot_\\d+'))
dev.off()
```

Of course you can do this also manually.

```
pdf('foo.pdf')
mget(c("ggplot_01", "ggplot_02"))
dev.off()
```

*Note:* If you plan to use this in a function (i.e. in a different environment than where your plots live), you should define e.g. `mget(ls(..., envir=.GlobalEnv), envir=.GlobalEnv, ...)`.

---

*Data:*

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot_01 <- ggplot(data=mtcars, mapping=aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
ggplot_02 <- ggplot(data=mtcars, mapping=aes(x=am, y=mpg)) + geom_point()
```